# Vue.js gives blank screen in WKWebView

Tags: ios, vue.js, wkwebview

Following is the code which gives blank screen in WKWebview. Tried to check error by adding

- webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error)
- webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,
  decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy)

But it does not give any error either.

```
    import UIKit
    import WebKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
        
        @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var logTextView: UITextView!
        
        var webView: WKWebView?
        var javascript: Javascript?
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            
            var webFrame = self.container!.frame
            webFrame.origin.x = 0
            webFrame.origin.y = 0
            
            // Create a configuration for the preferences
            
            
            let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            config.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
           
            self.webView = WKWebView(frame: webFrame, configuration: config)
            self.webView?.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
    
            self.container!.addSubview(webView!)
            
            let testUrl: URL! = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "dist")
       
            self.webView!.loadFileURL(testUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: testUrl)
            self.javascript = Javascript(webView: self.webView!)
            self.webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        }
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,
                     decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
            
            if let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print(response.statusCode)
                if response.statusCode == 401 {
                    // ...
                }
            }
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple but hard to find -
In index.html  we had links  like "src="/js/chunk-xxx.78xe86ad.js",    you need to take out the 1st "/" in the links.
Works like a Charm!!!